# How to validate session in php?

Tags: php, session

I want to some users can access to a page and others user can't but I don't know how to valide my session variable in my index for example. How I have to the top of my index.php page to validate that only some users can see that page?

This is the process for my login

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'db.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn_entrar']))
{
    $user=$_POST['usuario'];
    $password=$_POST['contraseña']; 
    $admin='Administrador';
    $vendedor='Vendedor';

    $query_admin = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE usuario='$user' 
              AND contra='$password' AND cargo='$admin'") or die($mysqli->error());


    $query_ven = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE usuario='$user' 
              AND contra='$password' AND cargo='$vendedor'") or die($mysqli->error());

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_admin)==1)
    {
        $row = $query_admin->fetch_array();
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id_empleado'];
        header("location: index.php");
    }
    else if(mysqli_num_rows($query_ven)==1)
    {
        header("location: index_empleados.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Usuario o contraseña son incorrectos')</script>";
        header("location: login.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: Never store plain text password

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no reason to do two queries. Just do one query to check the username and password. Then you can test `$row['cargo']` to determine what kind of user they are.

So if the username and password query is found, you can do something like:

```
$_SESSION['cargo'] = $row['cargo'];
```

Then at the top of pages that should only be visible to administrators, you can do:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['cargo'] != "Administrador") {
    header("Location: index_empleados.php");
    exit;
}
```